# Invisible reCAPTCHA v2 get response?

Tags: recaptcha

How can i get the response when invoking grecaptcha.execute() ?

My grecaptcha.getResponse() is empty.

I think i must catch an event no ?

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Comment: Show some snippet of your code

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple :

grecaptcha.execute();

var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

And then i wanted to do my server validation.

I am missing something about a async call for the validation.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to the question?  If the intent here was to clarify the question being asked and not to provide an answer, please remove this answer and edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up to use simply by adding that property to my div :

```
data-callback="recaptcha_callback"
```

and this script:

function recaptcha_callback() {
 
             validCatcha(); 
 
      
    }